# Load template if checkbox is checked in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm playing around with Meteor and want to do something simple. If a checkbox is checked, load a template. So I've got:

```
<body>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checker">
    Load Text
  </label>
  {{> check}}
</body>

<template name="check">
  {{#if isTrue}}
    <h3>Some Text</h3>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

I'm thinking I would need a Session to keep state. So I wrote:

```
Session.setDefault('key', false);
Template.check.isTrue = function() { Session.get('key'); };
Template.check.events({
  'change #checker': function() {
    if (document.getElementById('#checker').checked)
      Session.set('key', true);
    else
      Session.set('key', false);
  }
});
```

I think I'm confused how Sessions work in Meteor. Any hints or help are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to bind your event to a parent template in this case; eg:

```
<body>
  {{> parentTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="parentTemplate">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checker">
    Load Text
  </label>
  {{> check}}
</template>

<template name="check">
  {{#if isTrue}}
    <h3>Some Text</h3>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

And the js:

```
Session.setDefault('key', false);

// Edit: It appears that this is deprecated
// Template.check.isTrue = function() { Session.get('key'); };

// Use 'helpers' instead
Template.check.helpers({
  'isTrue': function () {
    return Session.get('key');
  }
})

Template.parentTemplate.events({
  'change #checker': function() {
    // Also, no need for the pound sign here
    if (document.getElementById('checker').checked)
      Session.set('key', true);
    else
      Session.set('key', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It could be something I'm missing, but I'm not able to get your code to work.

Comment: Updated the answer (needed return in helper, and "Template.check.isTrue = ..." is deprecated).

Comment: Awesome. I had seen somewhere that syntax was old, but thought it still worked. Putting it in a parent template seemed to be the key part I was missing.

Comment: It looks like I also could have chosen not to use the parent template idea and used 'Template.body.events({...}).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, for loading dynamically the template, we will have the exact thing like that: `dynamic template`

```
<body>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checker">
    Load Text
  </label>
  {{>Template.dynamic template=getTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="check">
    <h3>Some Text</h3>
</template>
```

And in the parent js file

```
Template.parentTemplate.events({
  'change #checker': function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).attr('checked')) {
      Session.set('template', 'check');
    } else {
      Session.set('template', '');
    }
});


Template.parentTemplate.helper({
    getTemplate: function(){return Session.get('template');});
});
```